# Flutter what does "Open for editing in Android Studio" do

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Perhaps this is a dumb question, but WTH... I've created a Flutter app in Android Studio, running it in AVD devices, etc. I've reached the stage where I'm looking to sign the app, and the docs tell you to use Tools> Flutter>Open for editing in Android Studio.

What exactly is this doing? What's the difference between the first editing session, and the newly created one? The new session has many more Build menu options, including the one necessary for signing, but why aren't these present in the first editing session?

I've tried looking for any explanations for this, and drawn a blank. Always keen to learn... :-)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking at: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview

Comment: "The first editing session" you mentioned is your generic flutter environment editing stuff. While "Open for editing in Android Studio" will show you your app's Android environment stuff, for iOS environment stuff, you will need XCode

Comment: It just seems surprising that in the first editor, it can still develop & run an Android app. And there is access to the various Android config files. Presumably this is therefore some sort of minimal environment.

Comment: If you open the android code in de Flutter project, you will have many red lines as if there were some errors. When you open for editing in Android Studio, you don't have that. There are also other function available when you open for Editing in Android Studio, like seen background activities when the app is closed (Notification for example).

Comment: @user3012629 Yes, mostly you will work with the first editor. Until its time when you need to do the signing and build apk, for publishing to the Google PlayStore for example.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question for a plugin I'm developing, because in my project, when I did `File -> Open -> (your project's folder)/android` in Android Studio, auto-complete for Kotlin worked, but it couldn't resolve any of these references in my Kotlin plugin file:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityAware
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityPluginBinding
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
```

so I was getting tons of:

> Unresolved reference: io

[image]

But, if I used the 'Open for editing in Android Studio' option from the root Flutter project, the same file would appear, with all the references magically fixed. I couldn't figure out what the magic was. Then I realised a subtle difference: it had actually opened the `example` project, with the android plugin as a module (notice the yellow arrow pointing to the example app). So, I think this is what 'Open for editing in Android Studio': it checks to see if there is an example project where it can resolve flutter libraries. It would be nice if this was actually explained or documented somewhere though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do it the simple way.
In android studio: File -> Open -> (your project's folder)/android and open it in a different window.